# Increase Navigation bar height for ipad

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

Trying to increase navigation bar for iPad

```
navgroup.height = 80;
```

Can any on suggest me for increasing the navigation bar for iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines states "Don’t specify the height of a navigation bar programmatically,".

So you can't, this is hardcoded to be 44dip on the iPad.

However, you could just make your own navbar view, with your own custom gradient, just float it to the top of your window, this is a start, with a background gradient and custom height of 50px:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    navBarHidden : true
});
var navBar = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : 0,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : 50, // Your custom navbar height
    backgroundGradient : { // Nice linear gradient, put your own custom colors here
        type : 'linear',
        startPoint : {
            x : 0,
            y : 0
        },
        endPoint : {
            x : 0,
            y : '100%'
        },
        colors : [{
            color : '#75060a',
            offset : 0.0
        }, {
            color : '#cc0000',
            offset : 1.0
        }]
    }
});
// I usually add a bottom border view, just looks better IMO
navbar.add(Ti.UI.createView({
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    height : 1,
    bottom : 0,
    backgroundColor : '#000000'
}))
win.add(navBar);
```

You may want to add custom buttons and titles to this to make it more functional but this should get you started. The nice part about this approach is you have the most control, and its completely cross platform (works on android quite nicely).

Comment: yeah, blame apple, but with this approach at least you can build for android / blackberry / mobile web as well as ios.

Comment: I don't blame apple!!! but its okay they provided some alternative for other second stage mobile too!!!